# Preset spinner in onCreate is overwritten

Tags: android, android-spinner

In an activity I have a spinner where the user can select which date should be displayed in the activity.

But in the previous activity there can be a preselection done. This preselection is passed to the activity by `intent.putExtra`.

The problem is that when I want to set the preselection with `setSelection` in the `onCreate` function it is always overwritten by the `onItemSelected` function.

How can I do this in the right way?

The code locks like this:

```
@Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // set layout
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);
    setTitle(getString(R.string.List_Title));

    // for alerts
    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setCancelable(false);

    // RecyclerView
    adapter = new ListAdapter_rc(this);
    lvArticle = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
    lvArticle.setAdapter(adapter);
    lvArticle.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    new ItemTouchHelper(itemTouchCallback).attachToRecyclerView(lvArticle);

    spListSelect = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spListSelect);
    adapter.dbm = new DBManager(this);
    ListAdapter_rc a = adapter;
    ArrayList<String> slDummy = new ArrayList<>();
    slDummy.addAll(adapter.dbm.listListGetNames());
    slDummy.add("Default");
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapt = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.spinner_item, slDummy);
    spListSelect.setAdapter(adapt);
    spListSelect.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            adapter.setList(adapter.dbm.listListGet().get(i).id);
            // THIS IS CALLED SECOND (i is always 0)
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {}
    });

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        adapter.adminMode = extras.getBoolean("adminMode");

        int i = (int)extras.getLong("listSelcted", 0);
        adapter.setList((long)i);
        spListSelect.setSelection(i,false);   // THIS IS CALLED FIRST (i has the desired value)
    }
}
```

Comment: Just move `setOnItemSelectedListener` code block after setting the Preselection and it should work .

Comment: I already tried this. It doesn't work. The onItemSelected Listener is anyways called after the onCreate function. It doesn't mind where the functions are called insed onCreate

Comment: `onItemSelected` will get called but i think the selection index should be the one you provided not 0 .

Comment: You are right. It seams to work now. It is a little bit tricky when to set what. But now it works so far.
Thank you!